# PDEs appropriate for adaptive time stepping algorithms

Tags: pde, ode, time-integration

I'm looking for some physical phenomena for which an adaptive time stepping algorithm would be ideal. A PDE or ODE that showed very large gradients in time at a small period of time and smoother gradients for the rest of the still necessary simulation. Thanks.

Comment: Adaptive time stepping is useful for almost any nonlinear problem.  There are a number of nice ODE and PDE examples where adaptive time stepping is relevant in the two-volume series by Hairer, Norsett, & Wanner.

Answer (score 2):

Predator-Prey could have the properties you want. Wikipedia has a good description, [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka–Volterra_equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)

[image: Wikipedia predator-prey simulation]

Alternatively you could solve very simple decay ODE with an impulse response. You would have three regimes:

1. Steady state
2. Impulse, in which the system is perturbed over a small time scale
3. Decay back to steady state

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = s(t) - ky
$$

Make $s(t)$ sharp and the solution will have a similar shape provided $k$ is large. Here $k=\tau^{-1}$ is the decay rate, the inverse of which can be interpreted as the decay lifetime, how quickly the system returns to equilibrium after the perturbation.

Answer (score 1):

ODEs modelling chemical reactions (chemical *kinetics*) are another good test case. When you have multiple reactions with different *rates* (some reactions are blazing fast, while others take a much longer time) you end up with a *stiff* system that is a good candidate for adaptive time stepping.

Here is an example from the classic book by Hairer and Wanner: the *Brusselator* (aka *the Brussels oscillator*, Chapter II.4, page 170)

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dy_1}{dx} &=& 1 + y_1^2 y_2 - 4 y_1 \\
\frac{dy_2}{dx} &=& 3y_1 - y_1^2 y_2
\end{eqnarray}

with initial values $y_1(0) = 1.5$, $y_2(0)=3$, $0 \le x \le 20$.